# MCB keeps tripping in irregular intervals, without any load connected

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

First random trip happened 2 weeks ago, then once in last week. Instant tripping started 3 days ago. Called an electrician, who suspected short-circuit and changed quite a few old sockets, replaced the old mcb(all mcb no rccb). Tested and it lasted for 5 minutes. Suggested full wiring inspection, which is very expensive for my budget. Turned the breaker on again after he left, this time it lasted 6 hours, next time was 16 hours, and then 3 hours, all without plugging in extra appliances, just a fan or a light running occasionally. As of two hours ago it is back to it's instant trip phase.

I would like to know what I might be dealing with here? can't be overload without load? using the same setup for past 4 years, no faulty devices as they are running fine on power outlet from other rooms. Short-circuit? is a major suspect but the irregularity of trips is casting doubt on that too. And is the diminishing interval between the trips any kind of pattern? like static/current buildup if that is even possible.

Comment: Current can't build up. Have you unplugged and turned off absolutely everything you can? Not sure where you are located, you might also try turning off all the other breakers and then turning on one at a time until the problem comes back. Of course if this is a ring main setup with few breakers that's not going to tell you much, but it's something at least.

Comment: Not quite sure what a MCB is, but if the new replacement is doing the same, then maybe a tiny break/problem in the insulation somewhere.  Very good(expensive) tools that an electrician should have should find it.  A light circuit might be able to use a plain circuit breaker(if allowed) and fix it, but with a different circuit it might be dangerous to you.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I'm not knowledgeable when it comes to this and was just looking for patterns

Comment: MCB is short for Miniature circuit breaker, the one in question is single pole upgraded from C10 to C16. I'm from Dhaka, electricians here mostly use cheap equipments. Everything is unplugged and it still flips.

Comment: If the breaker trips with it's load wire disconnected, the breaker is bad. If it doesn't but the breaker flips with everything unplugged, house wiring is bad.

Comment: @keshlam yes as the problem persists even after replacing the old breaker, wiring is the probable culprit. It's just the irregular interval of tripping that is confusing.  Electricians here lack good tools to diagnose the error without pulling out all the wires. As the process is pretty expensive for me, I want to keep it as last resort.

Comment: Intermittent shorts are the baine of all electrical systems. Could be something that only makes contact when vibrated, or rained in, or when hot, or cold, or... If you insist on chasing it down yourself, the solution starts with examining every connection anywhere on that circuit. If you don't find it that way, you are probably looking at disconnecting and reconnecting things until you isolate and fix the problem. There are ways to do that a bit more efficiently but they may need tools you don't have.

Comment: Is the breaker getting warm/hot to the touch when it trips?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel no it is cold. Sometimes it trips with a spark that trips the Rcd as well. Sometimes it just trips alone.

Comment: @keshlam did the connecting/reconnecting phase myself. Electrician already checked all the related switches and outlets. Was reading online about ground leakage and usage of clamp ammeters but I'm 99% sure the electricians in my area don't use one.

Comment: Does the MCB have a "Test" button on it?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica no test mode, just on and off

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem. I share a wall with my next door neighbor. Due to some unfortunate drilling on her side she damaged the wires inside my side of the wall. Though I disconnected that wall outlet years ago, apparently the damage grew over few months leading to current situation.